# AutoHotKey to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: autohotkey

I have 4 AutoHotKey programs, now, is there a way to convert the autohotkey codes to Visual Studio codes?
I need this, because I'm making a Visual Studio program, and needed a code that did something, so i was able to do it with autohotkey, but not with Visual Studio.
Maybe there is a website that convert it or something?

One of the codes is:

```
    #SingleInstance force
#Persistent

OnExit, ExitRoutine
xpos := A_ScreenWidth/2
ypos := A_ScreenHeight/2
hDrwArea := DllCall("GetDC", "uint", Null)
SetTimer, SetPixel, 1


SetPixel:

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos - 2, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos + 2, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)


DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 2, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 2, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos - 2, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos + 2, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)


DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 2, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 2, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos - 2, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos, "int", ypos + 2, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)


DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 2, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 2, "int", ypos, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 6, "int", ypos + 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 6, "int", ypos - 6, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos - 9, "int", ypos + 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
DllCall("SetPixel", "uint", hDrwArea, "int", xpos + 9, "int", ypos - 9, "uint", 255, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

Return

ExitRoutine:

ExitApp
```

Comment: what language?, visual basic, C#, ...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting Autohotkey code to C# or VB.NET, try making your AHK scripts invokable from another program. Compiling the AHK scripts to exes might be a good solution. Passing data back and forth can be tricky, but it may be easier than converting the code.

Comment: You can use a hidden window to communicate between running applications (there are better ways, but this is pretty easy).  Check out this thread: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/2672-inter-script-communication/

Comment: @BGM! Thanks so much for sharing this! This looks like a perfect solution to a problem I was working on. I looked and looked for a good way to pass data from script to script. I ended up writing to files on the sender and constantly looking for said files on the receiver. It works well, but it makes me feel gross. :)